# Does Dark Souls 2 allow random online mode?

Tags: xbox-360, dark-souls-2

I've been playing Dark Souls 2 on XBox 360 for over a year now and have logged over 150 hours. I do not play online and I do not have XBox Gold. Every time I start Dark Souls 2 I see a message, "You do not have privileges to be in online mode" and then I play though in offline mode.

But, every now and then, I get to start in online mode. This weekend for example, I started the game and I was online. I could see all the messages, bloodstains and I was even invaded and participated in the PvP arenas.

I reset the game a few times throughout the day and each time I came back I was still online. But yesterday (Monday) and today, I was unable to go online or participate in the online features like invading or dueling in the brotherhood of blood arenas.

This has happened a few times over the last year and even happened in Dark Souls 1 once.

So does Dark Souls allow everyone to play online every now and then or is XBox 360 temporarily giving access to gold features for a weekend promotion or something? What is allowing me to participate in online mode when I clearly do not have access to online play?

Comment: Have you ever had a separate user logged in at the same time when you were able to play online?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I only have 1 xbox live account in the house and it's not gold. Has not been for 2+ years.

Comment: That answers the question haha. As I explained in my answer, having a separate Gold account (possibly a friend?) *Might* give you Gold privileges in game, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- **It was a "[Free Gold Weekend](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/free-multiplayer-weekend)"** - this basically allows anyone with Silver subscription to play with full Gold-level capability.
- **You had another sign-in with Gold signed in at the same time** - I'm not certain, but this *might* allow you to play online. This does work for other things like DLC: if you have an account that has downloaded/purchased a DLC, leaving that profile signed in while a separate profile plays gives them access to that DLC.

Comment: +1 for free gold weekend. That's what it was I guess. I didn't get any notice when i logged in so that's really odd. I read that link and it says Oct 9-11 in 2015 was free gold weekend. I didn't even know they did that.

Comment: @DustinDavis yeah they don't really advertise it too openly.